# git-remote-http.exe is running for a long time

Tags: git, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on ionic project. Everything was okay but suddenly yesterday when I aimed to add google map to the project using [this link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps), ***git-remote-http.exe*** runs at background. I taught it's just for one time, thereby I waited almost three hours for it. Unfortunately seems anytime I add something to the project the same process goes on. 
[image]

It almost ruined two days of me. Please someone help me how I can get rid of this git process. Let me know if you need *config.xml* or *package.json* files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first which parent process has launched `git-remote-http.exe`, with which parameters. (Using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) for instance)

For instance, that process was seen with [gitextensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/528).

A possible workaround, to avoid this situation, is to:

- uninstall Git for Windows
- uncompress a [portable version of Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [`PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe))
- reference git.exe from that portable version in your Visual Studio Code

Then check if the issue persists.

Regarding the winpty-agent process, check [Microsoft/vscode issue 40729](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40729):

> The only way to make it stop is to not use the integrated terminal on Windows as `winpty-agent.exe` enables the feature.

---

The [OP Abdu4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7905439/abdu4) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395979/git-remote-http-exe-is-running-for-a-long-time/54396032?noredirect=1#comment95606214_54396032) having to do:

> - uninstall `npm`
> - re-install it
> - finally you need that process to run at least for once.

Comment: Thank for your response. These are all the processes. https://www.mediafire.com/view/saq4c2vxj43dksy/Capture.PNG/file

Comment: I will try your solution out, but when I'm using power shell or cmd of windows, the same result is repeated.

Comment: I had added git bash to visual code. Unfortunately the same result .https://www.mediafire.com/view/ecgt6afc5phfucd/Untitled.png/file

Comment: I noticed it cannot go ahead while it reaches to ionic-angular@3.9.2.

Comment: @Abdu4 Well done! Is there any additional operation you had to do to make it work?

Comment: actually yes, First, u need to uninstall npm second, install it and finally you need that process to run at least for once.

Comment: @Abdu4 Great! i have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.